# Kendo UI Grid em uma Diretiva do AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-directives

Como criar um Kendo-grid com opções reutilizáveis usando AngularJS?

Além das configurações padrão, o grid deve incluir dinamicamente uma coluna `checkbox` com a opção para selecionar todas as linhas. Os métodos para tratar as seleções devem fazer parte da diretiva e, de alguma forma, eu deveria conseguir ter acesso aos ids selecionados no *controller* da *view*.

Outro comportamento importante é manter no escopo do *controller* uma referência ao grid:

```
// no controller: $scope.grid
<div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="gridOptions"></div>
```

Abaixo um caminho inicial que eu imaginei, porém não está 100% funcional pois o AngularJS não compila as informações da coluna `checkbox`, portanto não chama os métodos do *controller* da diretiva. Ao mesmo tempo não sei ao certo onde forçar o $compile neste código.

```
myApp.directive('p3visaoGrid', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        gridConfiguration: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.gridIds = [];
        $scope.gridIdsSelected = [];

        var updateSelected = function (action, id) {
            if (action === 'add' && $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) === -1) {
                $scope.gridIdsSelected.push(id);
            }
            if (action === 'remove' && $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
                $scope.gridIdsSelected.splice($scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id), 1);
            }
        };

        $scope.updateSelection = function ($event, id) {
            var checkbox = $event.target;
            var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
            updateSelected(action, id);
        };

        $scope.isSelected = function (id) {
            return $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) >= 0;
        };

        $scope.selectAll = function ($event) {
            var checkbox = $event.target;
            var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridIds.length; i++) {
                var id = $scope.gridIds[i];
                updateSelected(action, id);
            }
        };
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var baseColumns = [
            {
                headerTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ng-click="selectAll($event)" ng-checked="isSelectedAll()">',
                template: '<input type="checkbox" name="selected" ng-checked="isSelected(#=Id#)" ng-click="updateSelection($event, #=Id#)">',
                width: 28
            }
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridConfiguration.columns.length; i++) {
            var column = $scope.gridConfiguration.columns[i];
            baseColumns.push(column);
        }

        var gridOptions = { ... };

        var grid = $element.kendoGrid(gridOptions).data("kendoGrid");;
        $scope.$parent[$attrs[directive.name]] = grid;
    }
};

return directive;
}]);
```

Comment: Ja deu uma olhada nessa pagina "The Grid widget in Angular-Kendo"? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget